How to measure correctness of an area
Given a 2D image of a puppy, the algorithm identifies which pixels are the puppy. In other words the silhouette of the puppy.  I want to measure the correctness by comparing against a known-good result. Should I use DICE score for that?  I tried to use DICE but it isn't working.  Suppose the silhouette is typically correct within 3 pixels, for large puppies I get DICE 0.9, but for small puppies I get DICE 0.5.
The reason is that part of the error is the algorithm and part is from the pixelization.  So how can I compute an adjusted DICE that measures only the algorithm error and ignores the pixelization error?
